# How to update model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

guys.
I have an ASP.NET MVC page where the model is being edited.
On each action executing I have a new controller, so I don't get an updated model.
I'm saving a model instance into Session["MyModelKey"]. But every time an action is executed, I have unmodified instance there even if I have changed values in textboxes which were created like this:

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EMail)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EMail)
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Country)
 @Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyController")

Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
       //Every time this action is executed - I have a new controller instance
       //So I have null in View.Model
       //I get Session["MyModelKey"] here, 
       //But the model instance properties are not updated 
       //even though I have updated E-mail and Country properties of the model in the UI
    }
}
```

So, how can I get an updated model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: edited to bring more sence into question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to save to session the model binder will work behind the scenes to match the posted form values to your model properties.

Make sure you use a submit button though, and wrap the UI elements with a form so the page will post.  Your action link will not have the same outcome.

```
public class SomeFormModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(SomeFormModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case Model has a collection property. In the view, I have "Add" link and "Remove" link for each item of collection. So, it is not working for me :(

Comment: Yes, this example works for regular form posts.  You might need to set up some routes and use some ids as part of the route path, and the links can hit other actions, perform something, then redirect back to the original page to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pst back your view to an action method that has the model as a parameter. The asp.net model binder will create the parameter and fill in the properties based upon a naming convention (property name same as input element name). This will get you a copy of any content changed by the user.

Comment: doesn't help much. Works only if the model is simple type like int/string/etc.

Comment: can you post your model code? the model binder can build fairly complex types. you can also build your own model binder.

Comment: a model is an Entity from the EF Model. Did you consider that I have a new controller instance on each action invocation?

Comment: Here is an example of how to post back data to an asp.net mvc action method that uses model binding. You need to mark one of your action methods with the [HttpPost] attributes. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Comment: I believe it's not about the Attributes. And it will work only when you have the same controller instance all the time you use the same Model object.

Comment: Still a bit confused. Here is a concrete example of how to have one controller render a form that posts to another controller and the model binding works. http://bobcravens.com/files/model_binding.zip